# Unable to access an mitmproxy via https from another machine

Tags: ssl, https, ssl-certificate, mitmproxy

I'm trying to do a reverse proxy to GitHub for testing purposes, so I'm running the following on an ubuntu 20 vm:

`sudo ./mitmdump -p 443 --mode reverse:https://github.com`

When on that same vm, I can curl localhost like so: `curl https://localhost --cacert mitmproxy-ca-cert.pem`, and everything works.

I scp'd the pem, and try to run the same on my Mac

```
curl https://10.1.1.1 --cacert mitmproxy-ca-cert.pem
```

, but I get the error

```
curl: (60) SSL: no alternative certificate subject name matches target host name '10.1.1.1'
More details here: https://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html

curl failed to verify the legitimacy of the server and therefore could not
establish a secure connection to it. To learn more about this situation and
how to fix it, please visit the web page mentioned above.
```

Comment: You should better add an entry for 10.1.1.1 to github.com in the hosts file on the mac so that the host name matches.

Comment: Can you upgrade to the latest development builds? If that doesn't fix things, please file an issue on GitHub. :)

Comment: @Robert why would that be an issue for my Mac and not when using localhost on the linux vm though?

Comment: @MaximilianHils I'll give that a shot

Comment: Because HTTPS includes a validation of the requested hostname. If you request `10.1.1.1` but the site that answers has the certificate of `github.com` then of course the SSL validation will fail as your posted error message shows. At least you should specify the correct host name in curl: `curl -H "Host: github.com" https://10.1.1.1 --cacert mitmproxy-ca-cert.pem` this may work, but the safe way is editing the hosts file.

Comment: @Robert: Yes - the caveat here is that mitmproxy should detect that cURL is sending the expected host as part of the TLS handshake and should mirror that value in the forged certificate.